# How to use auto_link inside of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I need to build a JSON object. How can I use auto_link() inside my controller? Right now it errors:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `mail_to' for #<ConversationsController:0x144c3f880>):
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:48:in `html_format'
  app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:326:in `comments'
  app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:322:in `comments'
```

Thank you for any ideas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`auto_link` is an helper and you can only reference if from a view. And there's a reason for that: representing information is a view responsibility.

In your case, either create a JSON template or, if you really really really need to use the helper in the controller, include the `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` module in your controller.

```
class ConversationController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
end
```

You might also need to include al dependencies, such as the module that contains `mail_to` helpers.

Comment: Thank you! (literally working on this one all day. I tried your suggestion but that still breaks, error "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<ConversationsController:0x1116d6098>):"

Comment: How do I include all the mail_to helpers? Also, how do I create a JSON template, that sounds very smart, but I haven't seen any example on that. Right now I build an array in the controller (using helpers) and then render :json => @comments

Comment: You can create a JSON template handler, like Rails does with Builder for XML.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the `auto_link` function is removed from rails 3.1 you can use the `rails_autolink` gem instead.
https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink