# Auto_link with rails_autolink gem - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I'm trying to use the rails_autolink gem.
As usual, I added the gem declaration to my gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_autolink'
```

Then ran "bundle install", restarted my rails local server and
Then I added to my posts_controller the require before the class declaration

```
require 'rails_autolink'
class PostsController < ApplicationController
     ...
```

and used the auto_link method inside my create action

```
    def create
        @new_post = Post.new(params[:post])

        if @new_post.content == ""
          redirect_to posts_url
        else
         @new_post.content = auto_link(@new_post.content)

         ... #respond_to and save methods
        end
    end

end #end of my post controller
```

The thing is that when I try to create a post I have a undefined method on the auto_link method, any idea why ? Is it specific to the gem or is it because something else ?

Comment: the real question is why are you using auto_link in your controller? rather than your view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a view helper which you're trying to use in a controller

```
@new_post.content = view_context.auto_link(@new_post.content)
```

Comment: allright thanks so if I only use it in a view do I still need the require in my controller ?

Comment: I'd have thought not but try it out. Personally I'd put this in a view file anyhow.

Comment: and sorry just to rectify the method is "auto_link" and not "autolink" as  mistyped on my post

Comment: Anyone have a full answer here?  I'm trying to put in in the controller (working with the auto_html gem), but oddly, this doesn't work:  ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper.auto_link.  Edit, this did it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161353/how-to-use-auto-link-inside-of-a-controller

Answer (score 2):

In any other places you can use: `ActionController::Base.helpers.auto_link(text)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need the namespacing. Try it again simply using:

```
auto_link(@new_post.content)
```